# Forget previously logged in facebook user?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

When I promt the user to log in with their facebook account I do it like this:

```
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["email"], allowLoginUI: true) { (session, state, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && state == .Open {
            FBRequest.requestForMe().startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, data_, error) in
                println("Facebook data: ")
                if error == nil {
                    let facebookInfo = data_ as NSDictionary

                }
            })
        }
        else {
            self.SuperVC!.presentAlertView("Error", message: "Could not connect with facebook.", decline: "Ok", others: [])
        }
```

Now, when its the first time logging in the user can enter their email and password... but the next time its not possible to do so, it remembers the previous user even if I clear token info like this:

```
FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
```

**I clear the token before promting to login, for testing purposes.**

It only forgets if I reset the entire app, by deleting it or in the simulator 'Reset contents and settings'

Lets say that another user wants to log in on the same device, it is not possible.

How do I make it forget the previous user?

Comment: Can you include the actual code from your `closeAndClearTokenInformation()` call? I'm currently using that method to clear the session information and it works for me.

Comment: FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation(). I have it in my AppDelegate for testing.

Comment: What is your SDK version? Have you tried your code on real device? Could you please provide more concrete code? I mean full method where you remove your token information and method where you perform your request.

Comment: Im on xcode 6.1.1 ios 8

Comment: In simulator it goes directly to the permission accept (which is after you enter your email and pw). And on device it just loggs in automatically. Am I using the wrong method to clear this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using another method for promting the user credentials.

I used

```
FBSession.activeSession().openWithBehavior(FBSessionLoginBehavior.ForcingWebView, completionHandler:{
    // Stuff...
}
```

With the `.ForcingWebView` it always starts over and promting the users ceredntials.

Comment: Swift 3/4 version?

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the solutions above worked.

I was able to logout, but no way to change the user on the next login screen.

I found a way to change the user after logout from FB by initializing the FBSDKLoginManager as follow :

```
faceBookLoginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
faceBookLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

When using the above code, after the logOut was done using `[faceBookLoginManager logOut];` FB login popup asks again for user name/password so another user can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook SDK takes your facebook login access from Safari. App forgets who the previous user was, if you just sign out of facebook in Safari.

Comment: Or in the simulator. Go **Settings>Safari>Clear History and Website Data**, for the nuclear option

Answer (score 0):

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
 [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

Comment: How to do this using latest API's? ( FacebookLogin, FacebookCore, and FBSDKLoginKit  )